Best way to create Enums with hierarchy
I want to create Enums that have hierarchy to simplify argument validation, type checks, etc. For example, say I want to enumerate the different types of employees in a company, split across department:
class ProductEmployee(Enum):
    PM = 1
    ANALYST = 2
    MANAGER = 3

class EngEmployee(Enum):
    DATA_ENG = 1
    FRONTEND_DEV = 2
    BACKEND_DEV = 3

What I tried: Create a new Enum encompassing both:
class Employee(Enum):
    PM = ProductEmployee.PM
    ANALYST = ProductEmployee.ANALYST
    MANAGER = ProductEmployee.MANAGER
    DATA_ENG = EngEmployee.DATA_ENG
    FRONTEND_DEV = EngEmployee.FRONTEND_DEV
    BACKEND_DEV = EngEmployee.BACKEND_DEV

Expected behavior is that different types can both be considered the same "supertype." For example, an integer is both an int and a numbers.Number, and a float is likewise a numbers.Number:
print(isinstance(1, numbers.Number))                    # True
print(isinstance(1, int))                               # True
print(isinstance(1.2, numbers.Number))                  # True

So ideally, I would want an Employee.PM to count as both an Employee and as a ProductEmployee. Here's what I actually get:
print(isinstance(Employee.PM, Employee))                # True
print(isinstance(Employee.PM, ProductEmployee))         # False
print(isinstance(Employee.PM._value_, ProductEmployee)) # True

Technically this can work, but the fact that I have to use ._value_ feel wrong. Is there a better way to create type hierarchies using Enum?

You mean class Employee: pass / class ProductEmployee(Employee, Enum): ...?

This is not really what enums are meant for.

You can inherit from enums as long as they do not have any members:
from enum import Enum

class EmployeeType(Enum):
    # add any common behavior here
    def emp_type(self):
        """
        silly example of shared behavior
        """
        return self.__class__.__name__[:-12]


class ProductEmployeeType(EmployeeType):
    PM = 1
    ANALYST = 2
    MANAGER = 3

PM, ANALYST, MANAGER = ProductEmployeeType


class EngEmployeeType(EmployeeType):
    DATA_ENG = 1
    FRONTEND_DEV = 2
    BACKEND_DEV = 3

DATA_ENG, FRONTEND_DEV, BACKEND_DEV = EngEmployeeType

and in use:
>>> isinstance(PM, EmployeeType)
True

>>> isinstance(PM, ProductEmployeeType)
True

>>> DATA_ENG.emp_type()
'Eng'


1 Disclosure:  I am the author of the Python stdlib Enum, the enum34 backport, and the Advanced Enumeration (aenum)  library.
